# Javascript addEventListener within addEventListener

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouseevent, addeventlistener

This could be a silly question, but I'm having a hard time with a sequence of event listeners that shouldn't be running all the time basically. I want to click a button that will allow certain mouse events to be performed on a `<canvas>` element. On `mousedown` there is something logged to the console, and as long as the the mouse is down I want another statement logging to the console, and then on `mouseup` there should be a final statement and the `mousemove` logging will cease. At current, anytime after the first `mousedown`, there is `mousemove` logging, completely ignoring the `mUp` boolean to stop it. It might be that there's something wrong about nesting Event Listeners, but I wasn't really aware of any problems it might cause...

Here's my code so far, any help would be appreciated:

```
function mouseMove() {
    var mX = canvas_x,
        mY = canvas_y;

    console.log('move: ' + mX + ',' + mY + ',' + mouseup);
}

btnRect.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    dRect = false;

    c.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        var x = canvas_x,
            y = canvas_y;

        mouseup = false;

        console.log('down: ' + x + ',' + y + ',' + mouseup);

        if(mouseup === false) {
            c.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
        } else if (mouseup === true) {
            c.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
        } else {
            c.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
        }
    });

    c.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        var eX = canvas_x,
            eY = canvas_y;

        mouseup = true;

        console.log('up: ' + eX + ',' + eY + ',' + mouseup);
    });

});
```

Comment: can you provide whole code or jsfiddle?

Comment: Why do you need three cases in your `if (mouseup === false)` block? Either it's false or true, why do you need another `else`?

Comment: I only added the third condition to attempt to catch something else that might've been happening behind the scenes. Whether it's false or true, it just runs for some reason.

Comment: The `mousedown` event is only triggered when the mouse button is pressed, not repeatedly while the mouse is down.

Comment: You should call `removeEventListener` in the `mouseup` handler.

Comment: The `if` is totally useless. You unconditionally set `mouseup = false` two lines before -- nothing can change it between there and the `if(mouseup == false)`.

Comment: Damn, I don't know why I didn't think about it like that before! Thankyou so much, you've made my day!